# Footnotes running off edge of page

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, footmisc

When using long section titles and the `para` option from `footmisc`, the footnotes are pushed off the edge of the page. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
    \section{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long section title.}
        This is some text.\footnote{\lipsum[1-6]}
        \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Remove the `para` option to see the difference. How can I prevent the footnote from extending below the text boundaries?

Comment: As the documentation of **footmisc** explains, the `para` option is intended for short footnotes. You can clearly see that paragraphs in the footnote are not respected. With that option, footnotes are *never* split across pages.

Comment: In my situation, the footnotes vary in length (5 to 20 words) and are high in number. I use the `para` option so that space is conserved as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run-in (paragraph) typesetting of footnotes in (La)TeX is tricky. An introduction to the problems faced is section 9 of the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/manyfoot.pdf) of the `manyfoot` package. With regard to the algorithm of `footmisc`, its `para` option needs to *"mess about with the output routine"* (`footmisc` documentation, p. 12). Page 13 of the `footmisc` manual states:

> We make a box out of the paragraph of footnotes, and then stuff the contents of the box into that which is going to be `\shipped` out.

Although I'm not familiar enough with LaTeX's output routine to be sure, I suspect that the "box" referred to simply can't be broken across pages.

Solution: Replace `footmisc` with the [`bigfoot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package which features the most advanced algorithm for run-in footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\begin{document}
    \section{This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long section title.}
        This\footnote{Yes,} is\footnote{it is} some\footnote{indeed.} text.\footnote{\lipsum[1-6]}
        \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the `bigfoot` package placing the fourth footnote on a new line? Is there a way to have it begin on the same line?

Comment: It seems that `bigfoot`s algorithm tends to place long footnotes on a new line. I don't know how to change this.